# Errorprone - Disable Checks in ViewBinding classes generated by ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife, java-annotations, errorprone

In our project we've just started using Google's Errorprone (http://errorprone.info/) to get additional checks during compile time.

I've managed to eradicate all remaining warnings we had in our project, but am Stuck with a warning generated within a ViewBinding class that is generated by ButterKnife. To be exact, the issue arises because I've created a custom view that uses generics to allow it to work on different Number types.

```
class MyCustomView<T extends Number> {
    ...
}
```

Within the XML layout file, an instance of that view is placed without the chosen number type, as it's not possible there afaik. Then, within one of our fragments, I just get a reference to that view with ButterKnife:

```
@BindView(R.id.customview)
protected MyCustomView<Integer> customView;
```

When running errorprone, this results in the following warning:

```
Warning:(42, 59) [unchecked] unchecked conversion
required: MyCustomView<Integer>
found:    MyCustomView
```

I fully understand what this warning means, but I don't see a way of getting rid of it without having to remove the generics in the custom view. Annotating the member field in the fragment with a @SuppressWarnings annotations didn't help either.

So I am wondering if anybody has an idea on how to solve this? **Can I disable the checks in generated code somehow?** Or just on files that containg "ViewBinding" in its name? Or does ButterKnife maybe need to make some adaptions to allow Errorprone to ignore these warnings?

I would be glad for any help! Thanks!

Comment: care to share the build.gradle file with the errorprone references - thanks